# Why aren't there 8 double bonds in octasulfur (S8)?

Tags: structural-formula

I know that the $\ce{S8}$ molecule contains 16 pairs of lone electrons. My teacher always says that we must try to reduce the no of lone pairs, so, had there been double bonds between 8 atoms of sulfur then the no of lone pairs would be reduced. Then why aren't there any double bonds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An $\ce{S}$ atom in a molecule must have 2 bonds to be neutral and in the $\ce{S8}$ ring it needs both of these bonds to continue the chain/ring. If you introduce some double bonded S atoms into the ring each of these will have 3 bonds and will thus be positively charged. So, while reducing the number of free electron pairs you increase the charge of the compound which would be wrong because $\ce{S8}$ isn't charged. You can only use free electron pairs to form double bonds if you have some electron deficient atoms in the neighborhood which can "receive" them.